# How to solve inequalities involving the floor function on both sides?

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This is my first question here. Would anyone be so kind as to explain how I can solve an inequality of the following form?

$$ \lfloor \frac{A}{x} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{B}{x} \rfloor $$

Here, $ A $, $ B $ and $ x $ are all non-negative integers (i.e., $ \geq 0 $). Further, $ A $ and $ B $ are constants and I am trying to solve for $ x $. For all intents and purposes, you can assume $ A = 4 $ and $ B = 6 $. That is,

$$ \lfloor \frac{4}{x} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{6}{x} \rfloor $$

Most posts I have read only involve a floor function on one side. Due to limitations in my mathematical abilities, I am unable to generalise solutions from those posts to solve inequalities with floor functions on both sides.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Here, I'd recommend letting $k$ be the common integer value, and then simultaneously solve $\lfloor \frac Ax \rfloor = k$ and $\lfloor \frac Bx \rfloor = k$ for $x$ in terms of $A,B,k$. One certainly only needs to check $|x|\le \min\{|A|,|B|\}$, since if $x$ is larger than one or both sides equals $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you for the suggestion, I did not think of that! I have since attempted to use your approach but am unable to get the solution $ x = \{ 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, ... \} $ for $ A = 4 $ and $ B = 6 $. Perhaps I was careless. I will check my workings.